# Advertisements in my Android application

Tags: android, admob, adsense

I have got question. If I want to add adverisements to my Android Application, I have to pay Google or no?
For example, if I create adSense and adWords account, I have to pay for it?

Comment: You don't have to, just create the Admob account (https://apps.admob.com/) and integrate into your app with their SDK.

Comment: Can you tell me, how I can "integrate into my app with their SDK"?

Comment: Just download it and follow the Getting Started Guide: https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you do not have to pay Google for them placing ads in your application. In fact, they pay you.